# PHP: Inserting foreign keys into sql DB

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have three tables: GPs, patients and appointments. The IDs for GPs and patients are also foreign keys in the appointments database. I am creating an insert form for the appointments table, but cant seem to get it to work. It gives the following error: "Unknown column 'date' in 'field list' ".

GP table cols:

```
GPID,
first_name,
last_name,
surgery_name,
surgery_address,
GP_photo
```

patient table cols:

```
PID,
first_name,
last_name,
address,
phone,
P_photo
```

my php:

```
<?php

include("includes/connect.php");

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $gp = $_POST['GP'];
  $patient = $_POST['patient'];
  $date = $_POST['date'];
  $time = $_POST['time'];
  $outcome = $_POST['outcome'];

  if ($date == '' or $time == '' or $outcome == '') {
    echo "<script>alert('One or more of your fields are blank, "
    . "please ensure you have entered content in ALL fields.')</script>";
  } else {

    $insert_query = "insert into appointments (GPID,PID,date,time,outcome)"
            . " values('$gp','$patient','$date','$time','$outcome')";

    mysql_query($insert_query);
  }
}
?>
```

My form:

```
<form action="appointments.php" method="post">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>GP:</td>
      <td><select name="GP">
          <?php
          include("includes/connect.php");
          $GP_list = mysql_query("SELECT GPID, first_name, last_name FROM GPs");
          while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($GP_list)) {
            echo'<option value="' . $row['GPID'] . '">' . $row['GPID'] . 
                    ': ' . $row['first_name'] . ' ' . $row['last_name'] . 
                    '</option>';
          }
          ?>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td>Patient:</td> 
      <td><select name="patient">
          <?php
          include("includes/connect.php");
          $P_list = mysql_query("SELECT PID, first_name, last_name FROM patients");
          while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($P_list)) {
            echo'<option value="' . $row['PID'] . '">' . $row['PID'] . 
                    ': ' . $row['first_name'] . ' ' . $row['last_name'] . 
                    '</option>';
          }
          ?>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Date:</td> 
      <td><input type="date" name="date"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Time:</td> 
      <td><input type="time" name="time"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Outcome:</td>
      <td><textarea rows="8" cols="40" name="outcome"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Book appointment"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Show your tables structure and clarify if you have three **databases** or three **tables**: they are not the same

Comment: oh dear, TABLES. I have three TABLES *goes to edit*

Comment: Replace your insert with `mysql_query($insert_query) or die(mysql_error());` and it will give you an error if one does exist. Edit your question with the error.

Comment: By no errors do you are talking about a white screen? (why are you using for example or in your if instead of || ?)

Comment: Thomas: The error I get is: Unknown column 'date' in 'field list'

Comment: @Cathrine Rydning In `appointments` exists the column `date`? It is in YYYY-MM-DD format?

Comment: It does indeed exist and is formatted like that.

Comment: @Cathrine Rydning Please, use `SHOW CREATE TABLE appointments`, or `DESC appointments` and edit your post with the result.